# Can SQL Azure Globan Admin & created user passwords be reset/changed?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-administration

After I provision a SQL Azure Single DB - with a Global Admin login/password - can it be changed after the initial deployement via SQL Scripts?

Can the passwords for the SQL logins/user created by the above Global Admin -  be changed/reset after the initial deployment or setup via SQL Scripts?

Comment: https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks145/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESET PASSWORD FOR SERVER ADMIN**

You can do this after initial deployment through any of these - Azure Portal, AZURE CLI, PowerShell or SQL Scripts

*SQL*

```
-- You should be connected to Master Database for this Server
ALTER LOGIN [AdminAccountName] WITH Password='New_Password';
```

*Azure PORTAL*

Go to Azure portal, click SQL Servers, select the server from the list, and then click Reset Password.

[image]

---

**RESET PASSWORD FOR OTHER USERS/LOGIN**

Yes, You can do this after initial deployment through SQL Scripts.

**Traditional model users**

```
-- You should be connected to Master Database for this Server
ALTER LOGIN login_name WITH PASSWORD = 'New_Password';
```

**Contained Database model users**

```
-- You should be connected to User Database itself
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD = 'New_Password';
```

See these links for more details:

[Contained and Traditional Model Users Syntax Differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017#syntax-differences)

[Azure SQL Logins and Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins)